# Get SparkSession in partition loop

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I'm using Java-Spark, I'm trying to get `SparkSession` in `foreachPartition` (rdd), What I'm trying is:'

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myappName").setMaster("mymaster");

Integer duration = 2000;

JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(duration));

//Get Kafka read message as stream
JavaInputDSteram<ConsumerRecord<Object,String>> stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
    ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe(inputTopics, inputKafkaParams));

    stream.foreachRdd(rdd -> {

        //my logic
        rdd.foreachPartition(iterator ->{
            SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate(); // null
            Dataset<String ds = sparkSession.createDataset(myJsonList /*ArrayList<String>*/, org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.STRING());
        );


    );

 }
```

But the following line: `SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate();`
returns always null,
How can I get the SparkSession in partition loop? I just want to use SparkSQL to do some logic on JSON and to get DataSet etc,

How can I solve it?

*maybe I have type on code

Thanks!

Comment: If you're trying to read JSON from Kafka as a Dataframe, shouldn't you be using Structured Streaming?

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: Read the documentation?

Comment: @cricket_007, sure